# How to connect hyperlink with our program

Tags: c#, hyperlink, code-behind

I have problem, i don't know how to connect hyperlink with my program.
I want add to registry key until install which connect file extension with my program.

e.g. I have hyperlink on website which open file .xyz, and i wannna browser "open file as [my_program_in_c#]".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the following registry keys, perhaps during installation

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.xyz]
@="dawid.xyz.1.0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.xyz\OpenWithProgids]
"dawid.xyz.1.0"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\dawid.xyz.1.0]
@="Description of the extension"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\dawid.xyz.1.0\DefaultIcon]
@="valid location of icon"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\atmelstudio.objproj.6.1\shell\open\command]
@="[my_program_in_c#"

or manually using [this](http://www.ehow.com/how_2073279_associate-extensions-windows-files.html)