# Permission Denied C# registry

Tags: c#, windows-8

I am trying to add a few registry keys to allow my application to open when they click on a particular file extension in IE.  (See [How to connect hyperlink with our program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14997114/how-to-connect-hyperlink-with-our-program) )

However, I am receiving a "permission denied" message.  How can I get around this?

Answer (score 2):

Run your program as administrator. And/or redesign it to not rely on registry locations that are not available to non-administrative users.

The whole HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE tree, for example, is privileged.